# I want to show a form by pressing the f5 key but it doesn't work in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, key, keypress

hello I'm just writing a program and I need to show a new form when I'm on a text_box and press the f5 key 
but its seem that the program doesn't recognize the f5 key, because I eve did a mini-program to find out the keychar of the f5 key and didn't work

I don't know if someone could help me with this
this is my code:

```
Private Sub txt_numero_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txt_numero.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.F5) Then
            fmrBuscarByName.Show()
        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `KeyUp` event too!

```
... txt_numero.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
        Form1.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: KeyUp system]

Answer (score 1):

Handle `KeyDown` rather than `KeyPress`:

```vb
If e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
```